# How to update partial view with value depending on dropdown list choice

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown menu within a partial view, that needs to change another dropdown menu in the same partial view depending on the selection from the first one.

The dropdowns within the partial view:

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            <label asp-for="ProjectId">Projects</label>
            <select asp-for="ProjectId" asp-items="Model.Projects" class="form-control" style="width: 195px; margin-right: 5px;" id="ProjectId"></select>

            <label asp-for="RoleId">Project Role</label>
            <select asp-for="RoleId" asp-items="Model.ProjectRoles" class="form-control" style="width: 160px !important;" id="RoleId"></select>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript function also within the partial view:

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $("#Projects").change(function(e){
                var val=$(this).val();
                $("#myTimesheetModal").load("/Timesheet/TimesheetModalAction/"+val);
            });
        });  
</script>
```

I am not sure what `#myTimesheetModal` is supposed to be.

Here is the TimesheetModalAction within the Timesheet controller:

```
public IActionResult TimesheetModalAction(int projectId)
{
    AddTimesheetViewModel addTimesheetViewModel = new AddTimesheetViewModel();

    //unnecessary code redacted
    //use the projectId here

    return PartialView("_TimesheetPartialModal", addTimesheetViewModel);
}
```

This code works the first time it's reached with a button press, but I can't figure out how to get back to this function with the new selected value of `ProjectId`

This code is from the index page, where the partial view is rendered from initially:

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary pull-right" asp-action="TimesheetModalAction" asp-controller="Timesheet" style="margin-right:8px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myTimesheetModal">Add Time</a>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myTimesheetModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            @Html.Partial("_TimesheetPartialModal", new AddTimesheetViewModel())
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So as far as I can tell I am not properly using the Javascript function to pass the selected value of ProjectId back to the Timesheet controller action in order to update the partial view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the javascript function to this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#ProjectId").change(function(e){
        var val=$(this).val();
        var url='@Url.Action("TimesheetModalAction","Timesheet")';
        $("#myTimesheetModal").load(url, { projectId: val });
    });
});
```

and now it works. `#Project` is now `#ProjectId` and I changed the `.load` function to take a url generated with `Url.Action`. I also changed the second parameter of `.load` so now it passes the val instead of concatenating it onto the end of the url string.

Now when the first dropdown value selection is changed, the `TimesheetModalAction` function is successfully called, with the new `ProjectId` being passed through.